# Did the Houston Police Department intentionally target the house on Harding Street?

Tags: united-states, criminology, police

In this video by [News Now Houston](https://youtu.be/9XmflR0MWXc) an investigative reporter suggests that the Houston Police may have raided the wrong location and killed two innocent homeowners (Dennis Tuttle and Rhogena Nicholas) merely trying to defend themselves and their dog.

I don't see anything about this by HPD. There are two addresses at play,

- [7815 Harding Street](https://www.google.com/maps/place/7815+Harding+St,+Houston,+TX+77012/@29.7093964,-95.2840052,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8640bdbda92a5bad:0x2f0eca316d7374e4!8m2!3d29.7093964!4d-95.2818112) were police officers in a no-knock raid killed a couple that had been living in the house for 20 years. House is well maintained near white fence; [neighbors left confused stating, *"they're far from drug dealers"*](https://www.click2houston.com/news/-they-re-far-from-drug-dealers-neighbors-upset-after-deadly-hpd-shootout), and [*"that man is a good man. I can't believe what went down."*](https://abc13.com/neighbors-of-couple-who-injured-5-hpd-officers-in-shock/5112373/)
- [7815 Hardy Street](https://www.google.com/maps/place/7815+Hardy+St,+Houston,+TX+77022/@29.8321483,-95.3583069,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m8!1m2!2m1!1s7815+Hardy+Street!3m4!1s0x8640b84d967564e3:0x70560171de2210ae!8m2!3d29.8321483!4d-95.3561129) a potential target for a drug house that matches the description provided by HPD. House is run down with burglar bars and new black iron fence and security system (not in picture from Google Maps). Also where [HPD is alleged to have stated in their press conference where the raid took place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPRnx.jpg)

It seems the first outlet to pick up the story is [reason.com](https://reason.com/blog/2019/01/30/the-cops-were-the-aggressors-in-this-wee?fbclid=IwAR1KWr3K0KHjk1uA64bnnTooY93H1nkFNWvo5hj8mlZteGznm7F9ZTksLFE).

Did HPD confuse the two houses and pull out the warrant for the wrong house, raid the wrong house, and kill two innocent middle aged homeowners and their dog?

Comment: I don't understand your title.  "Intentionally" or "unintentionally"?  And how do you suggest that "intention" be judged?

Answer (score 5):

## Update

It seems that now the FBI is involved and checking out the case. Here is what we know

- The warrant was requested by one agent, Ofc Goines.
- Ofc Goines lied about his sources.
- Ofc Steven Bryant who claimed he "witnessed" the original drug buy came clean and said he got the drugs from Goines's car.
- There was no handgun recovered, as detailed in the original allegation.

While HPD intended to raid that house, it seems now that the raid was illegal and conducted prematurely.

- https://www.houstonpublicmedia.org/articles/news/2019/02/28/323570/a-botched-houston-police-raid-and-its-consequences-a-timeline/

## Old Answer

While potentially not the right house, [the police chief addressed this doubling down (predictably),](https://abc13.com/hpd-chief-acevedo-addresses-conspiracy-theorists/5114859/)

> "I promise you, we were at the right house," said Acevedo.
>
> Acevedo commented that the investigation is on-going. He said he's aware of "conspiracy theorists" that have speculated that the officers raided the wrong home, but says they are incorrect.
>
> "There's a lot of conspiracy theories out there. People are running rampant. Let me just say this, 'We never run away from the truth,'" said Acevedo.

It seems at least now they're arguing they intended to raid this specific house.

Comment: But wouldn't such statements be typical of a conspiracy on the part of officials to hide the mistake?